# angular 2 share html and code between components in same area of the app

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I’m looking for a pattern and capabilities in angular2 to address the equivalent of ng-include in angular2 with something to also share code between components in same area of the app.

The use case: My app will have several different areas, each area has it own header/footer and behavior.

**App "areas" include:**

- /welcome – public content
- /login – still public but includes login,
  logout, registration, etc.
- /main – main end user part of the app
- /admin – administration area

Each area like this includes multiple components and templates.

At the moment I have template-html segments and component-code behavior that is manually replicated for all the components in an area.

Ideally I would like to class hierarchy or something similar to support this, so that code is written in one place for each segment.

Any ideas on how to implement that?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually i took the approach of using the a component for the common behavior and embedding the common component in the various places. Not sure if that is a good practice or not.

Here is an example:

Let say that the common html segment and the behavior around it is included in a component called common-component.

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'common-component',
  templateUrl: './common.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./common.component.css']
})
export class CommonComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

The in the various html templates i use this common-component element. Like in this example of my /welcome component:

```
...
<!-- welcome header and content go here -->

<!-- Common Component -->
<common-component>Loading...</common-component>

<!-- The rest of the welcome content and footer go here -->
...
```